# Unable to add cordova platform android on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu

I am running a newly installed ubuntu 14.04 system, I am unable to get past the following error, please help

```
hoomi@hoomi-Vostro-3446:~/work/boozing/boozing-mobile$ sudo cordova platform add android
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/4.0.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/4.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-4.0.0.tgz
Adding android project...

/home/hoomi/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.0.0/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Package name must look like: com.company.Name
Error: /home/hoomi/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/4.0.0/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
hoomi@hoomi-Vostro-3446:~/work/boozing/boozing-mobile$
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Package name must look like: com.company.Name
> ```

This tells it has something to do with your application's package name.

If you check your **config.xml** in your app's root folder, you will find your package name with the value against `id`. For example:

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
```

So, check the package name in there, [Android's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) will guide you for naming your package name:

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, **individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters**. To avoid conflicts
>   with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the
>   basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications
>   published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use
>   the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.
>
> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.
>   It's also the default name for the application process (see the
>    element's process process attribute) and the default
>   task affinity of an activity (see the  element's
>   taskAffinity attribute).
>
> **Caution**: Once you publish your application, you cannot change the
>   package name. The package name defines your application's identity, so
>   if you change it, then it is considered to be a different application
>   and users of the previous version cannot update to the new version.

If I can see it right, you may have used a `-` (hyphen) in your app's package name. So in that case, you will have to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

As per this [Answer by Mladen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29054456/1084619), you need to follow all the rules of writing the package name.

I faced the same issue where i had '-' in my company name