# ionic add platform android with custom android-target

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

Anybody knows how to add platform in ionic with custom android target ?
If I try this command :

> ionic platform add android

It always add android platform with newest android-target platform, anybody knows how to custom the android target without edit the manifest and custom platform add android version ?

Comment: When you download the android SDK, you can choose between versions etc. Or just run the SDK updater/installer, and mark the versions you wnat to download them

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To change the build version you want change your config.xml located at the root project's path.

Following lines add in config.xml and then settings are updated automatically at the time building android app.

```
<platform name="android">

  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="XX"/> 
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="XX"/>

  <!--other line code -->

</platform>
```

For Ionic2 please check my gist to [here](https://gist.github.com/santoshshinde2012/0e450707014c016c98e4ef3bf960845b).

Hope this will help you !

Comment: this doesn't work, I have try that and after ionic platform add android, it also create android-target with newest sdk (23)

Comment: this do after adding platform and for building use ionic build android

Comment: after ionic build, I think the app still target to new sdk, because in my device some view still horrible, not like before update of new cordova (that also update android-target to newest sdk)

Comment: can you check your AndroidManifest.xml in your platform/android folder

Comment: let me know which versions are there

Comment: after ionic build and before that update config.xml because i got the result in my system

Comment: ok, I have check and that's working, thank you..  I must found what update I've done that make some function in my app not worked, maybe I must downgrade ionic version...

Comment: Sorry, I found something strange, I open project.properties and found android-target still 23

Comment: Okay I finally found what is the problem, the problem is not the android-target, but how to get screen width and height that wrong.. thanks.. your answer has been accepted..

Comment: Would this work for Ionic 2 ? In Ionic 2 `<preferences>` are not in `<platform>` tag.. Also, I tried something : Do you know How I could make this work : `ionic cordova platform add android@4.1.1` ... Every time I do this I get `Error: Package name must look like: com.company.Name` even though [widget id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29147564/6266949) is of the required format

Comment: @jason-krs You can check to here https://gist.github.com/santoshshinde2012/0e450707014c016c98e4ef3bf960845b

Comment: I used this to bypass Google restriction to SDK 26 min target.

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to see all the versions of platforms installed in your project with:

```
cordova platform list
```

Then you can remove the current version with:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

And install the version you want/need with:
(in my case 6.1.1)

```
cordova platform add android@6.1.1
```

Source:
[cordova.apache.org documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html)

Answer (score 4):

if you are unaware about the version number try following command

```
cordova platform add android@latest
```

this will add latest platform to your application, make sure you try the following command to verify if it breaks anything.

```
cordova build android
```