# Ionic App - Plugin not found after update to Cordova Android 8.1.0

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I was working on my ionic 4 app. Now few days back Google Play Console has mentioned to set TargetSdkVersion to 28. So I just did the same.
I upgraded my cordova android version from 7.1.4 to 8.1.0.

Now when I've compiled the app, it shows whitescreen after splash. Upon checking in the Remote Device Console, I got this strange error.

```
plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryEntry.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Entry.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/DirectoryReader.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/File.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileEntry.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileSystem.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileError.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileReader.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadOptions.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileUploadResult.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/FileWriter.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Flags.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/LocalFileSystem.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/ProgressEvent.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/Metadata.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/requestFileSystem.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/browser/isChrome.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/android/FileSystem.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems-roots.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystems.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/www/FileTransfer.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseClass.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/www/FileTransferError.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseArrayClass.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/www/plugins.FileOpener2.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/LatLngBounds.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/LatLng.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Polyline.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Marker.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Polygon.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-file/www/fileSystemPaths.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Circle.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/CameraPosition.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/VisibleRegion.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/TileOverlay.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/GroundOverlay.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/HtmlInfoWindow.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/spherical.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/poly.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Common.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Geocoder.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/encoding.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Location.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/event.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/MapTypeId.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/KmlOverlay.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/KmlLoader.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Environment.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/MarkerCluster.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Cluster.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/geomodel.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/LocationService.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/pluginInit.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/CordovaGoogleMaps.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/googlemaps-cdv-plugin.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-media/www/MediaError.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-media/www/Media.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www/statusbar.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/call-number/www/CallNumber.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/commandQueueExecutor.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
plugins/mx.ferreyra.callnumber/www/CallNumber.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1352 Uncaught Error: Module cordova-plugin-app-version.AppVersionPlugin does not exist.
    at addEntry (cordova.js:1352)
    at Object.exports.clobbers (cordova.js:1362)
    at onScriptLoadingComplete (cordova.js:1677)
    at scriptLoadedCallback (cordova.js:1710)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (cordova.js:1664)
vendor.js:4062 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
cordova.js:1233 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1226 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
cordova.js:1226 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
vendor.js:158202 Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
(anonymous) @ vendor.js:158202
```

I have tried almost everything like uninstalling and installing the plugins, created new project, updated ionic, npm, etc. but no luck.

I have also installed android sdk api version 28 (android pie).

But if I am downgrading my app back to cordova android 7.1.4, it runs normal. Any suggestion is appreciable.

Comment: Check This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35573887/5909026

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I have seen this. But using this method throws white screen after splash.

Comment: Have you looked for messages in logcat as well? You may find that there is an incompatibility in the native code of one of your plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to upgrade my `Node Version to 10`. And updated `android-manifest.xml`.

It was working fine.

Thanks

Comment: @D.Hodges it is in platforms/android folder.