# Error: Error validating package name. Package name must look like: com.company.Name

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, platform, ionic3

i am trying to get the add the android platform to my project but i am getting error as the above.

This question is almost similar to this question [ionic platform add android- Package name must look like: com.company.Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013848/ionic-platform-add-android-package-name-must-look-like-com-company-name)

but mine is working good for ios but android alone facing this isse

i am clear it is related to the id name which is mine shown below

`<widget id="com.ionicframework.kmart102011-" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

> when ever i am trying to do `ionic platform add android` i am facing this issue.
>
> if i cange the id name then i will be facing problem with ios because my id in the provisioning certificate is like the above
>
> this working fine in android but now it is not working

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have special characters in your package name i.e the `-` at the end of your package name `com.ionicframework.kmart102011-` is not allowed.
Have a look at this post https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions for valid Java package names.

If you really need to have the package named that way for your iOS build, I would suggest specifying the android and ios packages separately:

```
<widget
    android-packageName="com.ionicframework.validpackage"
    ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.ionicframework.kmart102011-">
```

This has been added to Cordova-Lib as of this commit:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/commit/28ce0d1d8665caff4977622f6b178b7f4899896e#diff-1575c8da3c4f4f82ad443a5b131cbcc9R62

Answer (score 1):

Check the ".Name", it's not can be used with upper case, package names must be ".name"

Answer (score 0):

That id is not valid for Android.

What you can do is to use `android-packageName` and `ios-CFBundleIdentifier` to set the Android package name and the iOS bundle identifier independently from the id value.