# Cordova Unable to load platformapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm

I have been having this issue for few days now. Cordova won't run in browser, error says browser is not added as a platform. However, trying to add browser as a platform, cause another error which says Unable to load platfromapi from platform. It also says that browser is not a valid platform. See screenshots:

## Cordova issue 1

[Cordova issues 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIU2.png)
[image: Cordova issues 1]

## Cordova issue 2

[Cordova issues 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqm67.jpg)
[image: Cordova issues 2]

Comment: My comment will only apply to people trying to dual build a reactjs project: You will get this error if you do not have a `www` folder in your project.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Remove the platform which you try to run on it (browser, ios, android, and etc.)

```
cordova platform rm browser
```

Add the platform again

```
cordova platform add browser
```

You can run

```
cordova run browser
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked! It seems that the platform was trying to add/augment an older version of the browser platform (4.1.0 I think). However, when platform rm is used and the platform add is used, the updated browser platform is added (5.0.0)

Comment: tried adding and removing platform still getting error : Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa_global_php/platforms/.gradle/cordova/Api.js'
Failed to install 'mx.ferreyra.callnumber': Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform ".gradle" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. .gradle not supported.)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:166:17)
    at EventEmitter.module.exports.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/events.js:71:17)

Comment: at Object.getPlatformApiFunction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js:500:20)
    at Object.getPlatformApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:55:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:593:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)

Comment: at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
Failed to restore plugin "call-number" from config.xml. You might need to

Comment: try adding it again. Error: Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform ".gradle" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. .gradle not supported.)
Running command: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa_global_php/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qa_global_php

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! For some reason I had to run the remove command twice before it actually worked properly.

Comment: This isn't an acceptable solution for projects that have any native ios changes in their ios platform.

Comment: `add` and `remove` does not explain why this error happening and how can we prevent remove the native changes in the platform.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the plugin PlatformApi (or what its name is exactly) is not supported by the browser platform.

You can not use the "cordova platform add browser" because the plugin was not written to work with the browser

Maybe it has some specific features that can not be emulated in the browser.

Comment: The browser platform was working in the past. It just stopped working few days ago without any indication why. I have been working on my project for few weeks now and I've always tested functionality with the browser platform, until I started getting these errors that is!

Answer (score 2):

For those who's still experiencing this issue in latest ionic and cordova versions. Run:

1. `ionic cordova platform rm browser/android/ios`
2. `ionic cordova run --emulator`

Comment: Do you know How I could make this work : `ionic cordova platform add android@4.1.1` ... Every time I do this I get `Error: Package name must look like: com.company.Name` even though [widget id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29147564/6266949) is of the required format

Comment: people might confuse to run your command inline, it might be separately run, the real parameters was platform rm name/version/URL

Answer (score 1):

Goto Your `android studio` -> `tools` -> `android` -> `Sdk manager` -> `Sdk platform` and update Android 7+ and 8+ [image]

And then run

```
cordova platform rm browser
cordova platform add browser
```

Answer (score 0):

i saw this error when i tried to install the android platform that was too high for my current cordova cli, upgrading the cli solved it